# Text box styling

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Whenever I try to apply a style to a textbox, it becomes unresponsive to user input. Can you tell me a way to solve this?Here is the xaml code I am using:

```
<Style x:Key="textbox"
       TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
        <Border BorderThickness="3"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                Name="border">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="border"
                    Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="#9E5971" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: oh,by th way,whether it is or it is not focusable I get the same thing.

Comment: I deleted that line and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
<ContentPresenter
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

with

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
```

`ScrollViewer` named `PART_ContentHost` is a mandatory part of any `TextBox` control template. You should use [Default WPF Control Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) as reference instead of coming up with your own template.